# Знаки препинания в предложении с оборотом "словом, всё то..."

Tags: пунктуация

> Пришло время вспомнить о русской культуре отодвинув на более скромное место прочие наши устремления политические и другие приоритеты словом все то в чем мы поныне утверждаем себя.

Kакие существуют варианты расстановки знаков препинания в данном предложении?

Comment: У меня есть некоторое неодумение по поводу формулировки. Другими  словами, нет ничего важнее русской культуры, все ваши устремления отдвиньте на второй план.(?!) И далее. Мы себя утверждаем в наших устремлениях и приоритетах. (?!) Я думаю, здесь выражение "утверждать себя" употреблено неверно. Корректно: Мы себя  утверждаем в каких-то областях, у нас есть стремление утвердить себя.

Comment: Вроде бы нормально. Мы утверждаем себя (самоутверждаемся) в политике и прочих областях, но мало внимания уделяем культуре. А это та область, которая важна для самоутверждения нации.

Comment: @Ксения  Теперь понял: мы как нация утверждаем себя. А я понял, что речь о каждом в отдельности. Теперь эта фраза воспринимается по-другому и выглядит нормальной.

Answer (score 3):

*Пришло время вспомнить о русской культуре, отодвинув на более скромное место прочие наши устремления, политические и другие приоритеты — словом,  все то, в чем мы поныне утверждаем себя.*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

7. Если после однородных членов предложения перед обобщающим словом стоит вводное слово (словосочетание) словом, одним словом, короче говоря и т. п., то перед ним ставится тире, а после — запятая: Пшеница, просо, овёс, подсолнух, кукуруза, бахчи, картофель — словом, на что только ни взгляни, всё уже созрело’(Баб.).

Comment: Я бы еще пояснил, что первая запятая отделяет деепричастный оборот, а этот оборот включает в себя все, что стоит после запятой, до самого конца предложения (на первый взгляд может показаться, что оборот  заканчивается перед тире).

Comment: Да, можно это пояснить,  и других вариантов оформления подобных предложений я не видела. Но для меня не очень ясна его интонация. Дело в то, что в каждом сложном  предложении есть главная (центральная)  структура и интонация, определяющие его содержание, и здесь такой структурой является  однородный ряд дополнений.  Но тогда  начало деепричастного оборота вроде бы не выделяется паузой, мы должны сразу перейти к перечислению однородного ряда, а это фонетически не так просто сделать из-за большого объема фразы.  Поэтому мне кажется, что здесь верная грамматика, но не очень удачная структура(?).